# program cs call is ambiguous addidentity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0

when i try to run scaffold item and add identity to an existing project i get

> Program.cs(15,18): the call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext\<WebSeeSharpersContext\>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebSeeSharpersContext")));

builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebSeeSharpersContext>();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

I was expeting it would add my identity files to my project

Comment: do you have 2 versions of the identity libraries?

Comment: @DanielA.White how can I check that, sorry im a bit new

Comment: was this issue ever solved, i'm experiencing the same issue here. i'm preety 1 month into .net development

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The problem was that I had both Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore (7.0.4)
and
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity (2.2.0)
installed in my project.

After uninstalling the 2.2.0 Identity package, the issue was resolved.

To check and uninstall the packages using Rider:
either go to NuGet and manage the packages from there
or
right click on the project -> Edit -> Edit 'ProjectName.csproj' and delete the line of the package you don't need.